# Gulp tasks not working in sync

Tags: javascript, gulp

I'm trying to use `browserify` with `babelify` in my project. Everything works great except the problem of sync.

```
// Browserify
//---------------------------------------------------
gulp.task('browserify', function() {
    var bundler = browserify('_babel/script.js').transform(babelify);

    bundler.bundle()
        .pipe(source('_babel/script.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('_dev'));
});

// JavaScript moving and merging
//---------------------------------------------------
gulp.task('js-min', ['browserify'], function() {
    return gulp.src('_dev/_babel/script.js')
        .pipe(concatjs('scripts.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('_js'))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});

gulp.watch('_babel/**', ['js-min']);
```

From what I can tell, `browserify` notifies gulp that it's done (it's done very quic, 10 ms or so) when it's not. And then `js-min` moves old file. Such observation seems valid because I am always one change *behind*.

What can I do?

Comment: return the `bundler` in the `browserify` task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three ways to tell Gulp that a task has finished.

1. You have all sync stuff to execute in the task:

   ```
    gulp.task('task-a', function(){
      // do sync stuff

      // you may return here
      // but because everything is sync Gulp assumes that everything has ended
    });
   ```
2. You get the callback as input

   ```
   // the passed cb is the next task to execute
   gulp.task('task-b', function(cb){

     // do async stuff

     cb( result );
   });
   ```
3. Return a promise/stream (which fits your case):

   ```
   gulp.task('task-c', function(){

     // return either a promise or a stream
     return gulp.src( ... );
   ```

   });

In both cases 2 and 3 Gulp will wait the end of the execution before calling the next function.
You are basically writing a case 3 but Gulp believes it's 1.
To fix this just return the `bundler` and you should be fine:

```
// Browserify
//---------------------------------------------------
gulp.task('browserify', function() {
  var bundler = browserify('_babel/script.js').transform(babelify);

  return bundler.bundle()
    .pipe(source('_babel/script.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('_dev'));
});

// JavaScript moving and merging
//---------------------------------------------------
gulp.task('js-min', ['browserify'], function() {
  return gulp.src('_dev/_babel/script.js')
    .pipe(concatjs('scripts.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('_js'))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});

gulp.watch('_babel/**', ['js-min']);
```